When a submarine blows its ballast and rises, where did the energy for the ascent come from?
Suppose a submarine fills its ballast tanks with water at the surface and in so doing becomes negatively buoyant. It sinks, presumably converting gravitational potential energy into kinetic for the descent. Now at depth it blows the tanks and becomes positively buoyant. It's already used up its potential energy, so where does the energy for the ascent come from?

Are you just asking where objects that float upwards get their energy from? Or is there something unique to this submarine example?

It takes work to pump the water out of the ballast tanks. Now, remember that the submarineis neutrally buoyant just sitting at depth. It only takes a small change to make it positively buoyant.

You could also consider buoyant energy as potential energy in the same way as gravitational potential energy, but in the opposite direction.

@BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft does that mean that it is technically possible to reduce the energy stored in a body of water via ascending submarines? What happens if it runs out?

@JonCuster The ballast pump energy is entirely irrelevant. A submarine using lead weights as ballast could jettison them to surface without expending any energy at all.

TL;DR, It comes from the potential energy of the water above the submarine.

To add to the above, on the way down, the submarine and ballast lose potential energy, and some is gained by the water (the rest is dissipated). On the way up, the energy stored in the water is returned to the submarine. Total dissipated energy is equal to potential energy lost by ballast.

Buoyancy comes from a fluid exerting a net upward force pushing on a submerged object. As a floating object rises, the buoyant force does positive work on the object, and hence negative work is being done on the fluid by the buoyant force. As the object moves up, fluid moves down: the kinetic and potential energy gained by the object comes from the decrease in potential energy of the fluid.
Other answers/comments are talking about the required energy to pump water out. While this does require energy, this is not the energy that causes the submarine to float upwards. To see this, you can consider the case of a buoyant object linked to an object that will cause it to sink. One could then cause the buoyant object to "let go" of the sinking object to float upwards without the need to expend energy. Alternatively, note that the work done by the buoyant force is always the same regardless of how much water is expelled, assuming the submarine does not expel water by changing its enclosed volume.

To explicitly outline my point above

First, I am assuming the submarine is a "closed" object (not some object with holes where we still define the submarine as containing the fluid within the holes/open space that are connected to the external fluid).

Second, I am assuming the expulsion of water does not change the volume enclosed by the boundary of the submarine. If that is not how real submarines work, fine. The point of this answer is to look at where an object that floats upward gets its change in mechanical energy, not the specifics of how submarines work. Certainly, the argument works in the case of some sort of object that can expel water without changing its bounding volume.

As the submarine rises, the change in kinetic and potential energies of the submarine and its contents comes from the work done by the buoyant force: $\Delta K +\Delta U=W_\text{ext}=W_\text{buoyant}$

The buoyant force depends on the volume $V$ enclosed by the submarine (the volume bounded by the surface of the submarine on which hydrostatic pressure acts): $F_\text{buoyant}=\rho Vg$

The buoyant force doesn't depend on how much water is previously pumped out, since the bounding volume doesn't change when water is pumped out.

Therefore, the work done by the buoyant force doesn't depend on the amount of water that is previously pumped out.

Therefore, the change in mechanical energy of the submarine and its contents as they float upward doesn't depend on the amount of water that is previously pumped out.

What's the difference then? It's the division of that work between the change in kinetic and potential energies. The more water that is pumped means less work is done by gravity (less change in potential energy due to smaller $m$ with the same $g$ and $\Delta h$) and hence a larger change in kinetic energy, as expected.

To repeat just in case, this does not mean it doesn't require energy to pump the water out at some depth. It's just that the energy that pumps the water out isn't somehow going back to the submarine to increase the mechanical energy of the submarine as it rises.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Now at depth it blows the tanks and becomes positively buoyant.

This is not free.   As the openings are now at depth, it requires a large amount of energy to remove the water.   The energy to remove the ballast allows the ship to return to the surface.

From comments:

A submarine using lead weights as ballast can jettison them to surface without expending any energy whatsoever.

Of course.  If we have material more dense than seawater that can be released, that will decrease the average density of the ship.

But this answer suggests it's impossible to surface unless you expend energy to remove the ballast.

No, this answer is about the specifics of "blowing the tanks" to provide positive buoyancy in the question.

A submarine using lead weights as ballast can jettison them to surface without expending any energy whatsoever. But this answer suggests it's impossible to surface unless you expend energy to remove the ballast. That clearly isn't true - tie a floating toy boat to a cinder block, throw it in the pool, and watch it sink. Now spend 0 energy to cut the string and watch the the boat rise. The ship returns to the surface without spending any energy to remove the ballast.

Note that this is also how hot air balloons rise - they do not require any active mechanism to jettison ballast. You just passively drop a sandbag, you don't need to somehow energetically blast it out of the basket to gain altitude.

It doesn't take a quantity of energy to lift the submarine,
if it achieves  neutral buoyancy, because the
rising mass of submarine is balanced by the falling of
ocean water into its previous location.
It takes energy only to cause the buoyancy to change,
i.e. to expel water as ballast.   That energy is not proportional
to the mass of the submarine rising from the depths,
isn't the kind of lifting (unbalanced by counterweight)
that requires a force-times-displacement calculation.

As the submarine sinks, it pushes the water up. If a submarine of volume $V$ goes down a distance $d$ in a fluid of density $\rho$ in a gravitational field of $g$, then it has done $\rho gdV$ of work on the water. That is, the gravitational potential energy of the water after the submarine sinks is $\rho gdV$ greater than before the submarine sank. When the submarine rises again, the water does work on the submarine, and that energy comes from the gravitational potential energy of the water.

This is correct. To complete the picture, on the way down, gravitational potential energy is lost by the submarine and ballast, and gained/stored by the water. Some is dissipated by friction. On the way up, the potential energy stored in the water is returned to the submarine (but not the ballast). After a round-trip, the total energy dissipated is exactly equal to the potential energy lost by the ballast.

The high-pressure air in the compressed air system inside a submarine has a tremendous amount of energy stored in it. That stored energy lets the air perform work against the surrounding high-pressure water to displace it out of the ballast tanks.

Specifically, a tremendous amount of free energy $U-TS$; the internal energy $U$ isn't really dependent on pressure, so it's the low entropy $S$ that matters.

(Incidentally, I think this is the best answer. The Second Law drives the gas to expand, expelling water from the ballast tanks, and so the submarine becomes buoyant, making surfacing the equilibrium state.)

@BowlOfRed's answer is the correct one. But to further clarify that, let's illustrate the idea with a perpetual motion machine rather than your submarine, as follows.
To begin with, let's construct a big, long cylinder, say 1000 feet long, closed at one end and open at the other, and push the closed end down into the ocean. So the cylinder's full of air all the way down, surrounded by ocean water.
Now tie a 1000 foot rope to a heavy-but-buoyant log, and wrap the other rope end round and round a pulley. Drop the log down the cylinder, and it spins and spins the pulley as it falls the 1000 feet, maybe generating electricity or doing some other useful work.
And now for our trick. At the bottom of the cylinder is an air_lock/escape_hatch. So untie the rope and push the log out the hatch, and it'll just float back up to the surface. Then just re-wrap the rope and give the log a little nudge back over the cylinder's top edge, and it'll fall back down that 1000 feet again, generating more energy for you. Then do it again and again, etc.
Okay, so, as per @BowlOfRed, we already know what's wrong. Pushing the log out that escape_hatch at the bottom of the cylinder ain't as easy as I made it sound. If it were that easy, then the world would indeed have free energy forever, because there's no other problem with the device. Tis pity, tis shame; tis shame, tis pity.

I don't think that the ballast has anything to do with it. Consider the following scenario: instead of using tanks that fill with water, perhaps we attach a heavy stone to the bottom of the floating submarine. The submarine still sinks. At the bottom, we simply need to cut the rope attaching the stone, which requires barely any energy compared to blowing the ballast, but the submarine still rises.

It looks like a lot of people are not understanding @BioPhysicist correct answer.  So I will attempt to help...
Buoyant Force is defined as $F=-\rho g V$
($\rho$ = fluid density, $g$ = gravitational acceleration, $V$ = displaced fluid volume of the object)
Whether an object sinks or floats is a relation between the object's weight ($mg$) and the buoyant force.
If the water's buoyant force is less than the object's weight, the object sinks.  If they are equal, the object remains suspended at the depth where they are equal.  If the water's force is greater, the object will rise, until they become equal again.
Blowing the ballast reduces the mass of the object, which reduces the weight of the object.  $V$ remains the same. $\rho$ will decrease as the object rises, which is why, depending on the change in mass of the object, a new equilibrium can be reached before the object gets to the surface.
The actual answer to op's question is:  The energy does not come from the sub, it comes from the water.  As a counter point, the energy of the sub submerging comes from gravity, not the sub.  If the sub is under power, it can add force in one direction or the other via engine power, but the theory here is easier to demonstrate if the engine force is zero.

This is the clearest answer.


This doesn't reconcile with the fact that a neutrally buoyant
submarine can jettison arbitrarily little ballast to surface. You
claim that when going to twice the depth, you need to spend twice the
energy to achieve positive buoyancy. That's just not true, you can
simply jettison half as much ballast for the same total energy cost.
You can always go from neutral buoyancy to positive buoyancy by
applying arbitrarily little work - just expel any infinitesimal volume
of ballast water, and the sub will float to the surface. Surfacing
does not require more energy the deeper you go. – Nuclear Hoagie

You cannot expel an arbitrarily small volume of water to return to the surface. If the submarine were initially neutrally buoyant, it would not sink in the first place. Starting from neutral buoyancy, you have to take on a finite amount of extra water to sink. (In the example below, I take one litre of excess water.) To rise again, you have to expel that litre of water just to achieve neutral buoyancy again and a bit extra to achieve positive buoyancy and actually rise. If we only expelled $1/2 \ \text{liter}$ of water, the submarine would not rise. Expelling the water requires $mgh$ amount of energy where $m$ is the mass of the expelled water and $h$ is the depth. This required energy is proportional to the depth. What you are suggesting violates the conservation of energy. When the submarine with negative buoyancy sinks, it loses potential energy. To rise to the surface again requires an equal amount of energy. If that was not the case, we could attach a rope to a generator to generate electricity as the sub sinks and use less energy to return the sub to the surface. That would be a perpetual motion machine and a generator of free energy, which we know does not work in regular physics.

It sinks, presumably converting gravitational potential energy into
kinetic for the descent. - Michael Stachowsky

If we set the gravitational potential energy to be zero at the ocean floor for our reference level, the gravitational potential energy of a submarine that has a mass of $10,000 \ \text{kg}$ at the water surface $1,000 \ \text{m}$ above the ocean floor is $$mgh =10,000 \times 9.8 \times 1,000 = 98,000,000 \ \text{Joules}.$$ Once we flood the ballast tanks to achieve neutral buoyancy, we only need to add one more liter of water to make the weight of the submarine effectively $1 \ \text{kg}$, and it will sink very slowly. In other words, we can make the effective weight and gravitational potential energy arbitrarily small. In this particular example, the effective gravitational potential energy is now only $$mgh =1\times 9.8\times 1,000 = 9,800 \ \text{Joules}.$$ This is the energy lost while sinking. It will only require $9,800 \ \text{Joules}$ of work to get the sub back up to the surface, and this energy comes from the energy stored in compressed air or from directly running an air compressor.
Some answers talk about using something like a lead weight to sink the balloon, and when we cut the lead weight off at the bottom, the balloon rises for zero energy cost other than the effort of using a pair of scissors. There are a few problems with this analogy. To repeat this process, we would have to tow the lead weight back to the surface and reattach it to the balloon, negating any energy gains. The second problem is we are using water for the weight and not lead. Imagine the ballast tanks are full of water. If we fully open hatches on the ballast tanks to 'release' the water when at the bottom, it will change nothing. The submarine will stay where it is. We cannot release the weight of water the same way we can cut off a lead weight. To make the sub rise, we have to increase the amount of water displaced by the submarine or, equivalently, increase the volume of air inside the submarine. We do this by displacing the water in the ballast tanks with air. This does require energy because at depth, there is significant water pressure, and the air pressure required to displace the water has to be higher than the water pressure.
There is a claim that the energy expended on removing ballast is unrelated to the ascent change of height and potential energy:
The energy required to blow the water out of the ballast tanks is related to the depth descended. In the example above, we lost $9,800 \ \text{Joules}$ of potential energy, sinking to $1,000 \ \text{m}$. If we had sunk to $2000 \ \text{m}$, the loss in potential energy would be twice as much, and it would require twice as much energy to blow the water out because the water pressure is twice as much at the increased depth. So, the energy required to return to the surface is directly related to the energy required in compressing the air. A submarine that sinks to a depth loses a certain amount of gravitational energy (however small that might be), and conservation of energy demands that it takes that much energy to return the submarine to the surface.
Some other answers/comments claim the required energy to pump the water out is not the energy that causes the submarine to float upwards:
Consider a tall cylinder filled with water. We place a one-liter bottle that is filled with water and contains a small water pump in the water. Once the bottle is submerged below the water's surface, it will have displaced one liter of water, and the level of water in the cylinder will have risen by a predictable amount. As the bottle sinks to the bottom from there, the water level remains constant, but as it sinks, water is displaced upwards, so in this sense, we can say the gravitational potential of the water increases as the bottle sinks. This increase in the gravitational potential of the water in the cylinder is not what returns the bottle to the surface. It is not like the gravitational potential of a ball that is thrown up into the air. In that case, the gravitational potential increases as the ball rises and eventually, the ball comes to a stop and starts falling back to the ground. When the bottle arrives at the bottom, it just stays there until we take action. We start the pump in the bottle, and it pumps the water out of the bottle. The water ejected by the pump causes the water level in the cylinder to rise, and the potential energy of the cylinder water is indeed increasing as we pump the water out. Conservation of energy says that it requires at least as much energy to pump the water out of the bottle. The rise in the potential energy of the cylinder water comes from the energy used to pump the water out of the bottle. While the energy is temporarily stored as potential energy of the cylinder water level increases, the ultimate source of the increase in level comes from the energy used to pump the water.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Blowing the ballast takes energy, but that isn't the question.
The energy to rise is from gravity. The submarine is now lighter than the seawater surrounding it ... which is another way of saying the seawater surrounding it is heavier.
Gravity pulls the heavier (denser) matter down below the less dense / lighter matter.
So the submarine comes to the surface.

The energy came from the thermal energy of the compressed air used to blow the tanks. As the water is blown out, the air molecules collide with the water surface; as the water surface is moving away from the air, the air molecules bounces off going slower than it started, cooling the air and reducing it’s energy!
In conclusion the energy used to raise the submarine comes from the thermal energy of compressed air.

Why the downvotes?
